# Batch Loading screen with no Glitching/Lag

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Here is a bit of my batch Loading script

```
Echo                                Loading
Echo                                ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
Echo                                ºÛ               º
Echo                                ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
cls
Echo                                Loading
Echo                                ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
Echo                                ºÛÛ              º
Echo                                ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
cls
Echo                                Loading
Echo                                ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
Echo                                ºÛÛÛ             º
Echo                                ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
exit
```

Using the `cls` code to wipe the screen makes the screen look like a "Blink". Is there a better way to clear the screen for this batch file? TIA

Comment: My Computer has a crappy processor, so it runs slow. i just want a file that will run it smoother and seamless.

Comment: It's not totally your processor's fault. Batch is slow, it doesn't being compiled and built into an executable file (.exe), it rely on *cmd.exe* to run the script you made in *.bat*.

Comment: @darkfang, it doesn't blink on my PC so batch files are fast enough to not have a problem with printing a few lines of text at least on a fast machine :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just far from perfect less glitching option: Instead of repaint the full screen, repaint only the loading line (but this has to be last painted line in the screen).

The basic idea is to ouput the line ending with a carriage return but without a line feed so the cursor is moved to the start of the line to write again over the same line.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    Rem Get a carriage return character
    set "CR=" & for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do if not defined CR set "CR=%%a"
    rem The progress bar
    set "fill=[##########]"

    cls
    echo(:: computers were created to give humans time to think while waiting ....

    rem For each character in the fill
    for /l %%a in (2 1 11) do (
        rem Calculate the right part of the bar
        set "spaces=!fill:~%%a!"

        rem Output the left and right parts of the bar and carriage return
        <nul set/p ".=:: Loading something big !fill:~0,%%a!!spaces:#= !!CR!"

        rem Pause for a second
        ping -n 2 "" > nul
    )
    echo(
    echo(:: Done
```

If you can not change your code/design so the last line is the only one repainted, at least try to enclose the painting operation inside a block (code enclosed in parenthesis) so in each paint operation commands are only parsed once, and prepare everything before starting to paint. It will not avoid the glitches, but will be less evident

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /l %%a in (0 10 100) do (
        call :loadingScreen %%a
        >nul ping -n 2 "" 
    )
    echo(:: Done
    goto :eof

:loadingScreen percent
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Prepare everything 
    set    "sb=+----------+"
    set "fill=^|##########^|"
    set    "eb=+----------+"
    set /a "chars=2+%~1/10"
    set "spaces=!fill:~%chars%!"
    set "loadBar=!fill:~0,%chars%!!spaces:#= !"

    rem Time to paint
    (   cls
        echo(:: computers were created to give humans time to think while waiting .... %time%
        echo(
        echo(                           %sb%
        echo(     Loading something big %loadBar%
        echo(                           %eb%
        echo(
    ) 
    goto :eof
```

Comment: This is a good solution for a single line, but the op wants to redraw multiple lines. But perhaps it's easier to change the requirements than the solution

Comment: @jeb, yes I know it, thank you, but I though it could be an option.

Comment: I Used your code and changed a bit but the loading bar will only go halfway before the batch file will exit. what is wrong? My code is in this link: http://pastebin.com/5F8Z7FPr

Comment: @Jakers326, 1) counting in steps of 15 you will not reach the value 100. 2) The operation to calculate the two sides of the progress bar must be adjusted to the length of it. [Changed](http://pastebin.com/Uag2ez5e)

Comment: @MCND thanks for solving that one. it makes more sense now. thanks for all the help everyone!